# How to create thread with function parameter within function (C++, Visual Studio 2017)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, variadic-functions

I'm trying to create a class named ThreadMaster that safely handles all threads in the application. I want to be able to add a thread with any function to the ThreadMaster, therefore I need to use va_list (or somthing similar). However the thread constructor does not take the va_list as a argument (I think). I made the following code to test this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

void fee(int i) {}
void foo() {}

class ThreadMaster {
public:
    vector<thread> threads;
    /*void add(...) {
        va_list args;
        threads.push_back(thread(args));
    }*/
};

ThreadMaster tm;

void add(void(*func)()) {
    tm.threads.push_back(thread(func));
}

void edd(void(*func)(int), int x) {
    tm.threads.push_back(thread(func, x));
}

/*void odd(...) {
    va_list args;
    thread t(args);
    t.join();
}*/

int main() {
    add(foo);
    edd(fee, 6);

    tm.threads[0].join();
    tm.threads[1].join();
}
```

When I comment out the odd(...) function it compiles and runs without errors, but when it is there I get the following error:

```
.../xthread(238): error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
```

The weirdest and most annoying thing is that the ThreadMaster::add() function was compiling and running fine this way earlier, only when I rolled back from creating a join_all function I got this error. I don't have any clue as to why.

How do I pass my arguments to my ThreadMaster? I want to make the threads vector private, so I need to do it through the ThreadMaster::add() function. I strongly prefer not to install any non-standard libraries. If the error is caused by some setting in VS that I have somehow gotten wrong that would be the preferred solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

-- EDIT --

Following the comments I created the following template in tester.h:

```
class ThreadMaster {
public:
    vector<thread> threads;
    void add(void(*func)()) {
        threads.push_back(thread(func));
    }
    template<class T>
    void add(void(*func)(T), T t) {
        threads.push_back(thread(func, t));
    }
    template<class T, class S>
    void add(void(*func)(T, S), T t, S s) {
        threads.push_back(thread(func, t, s));
    }
};
```

And tester.cpp now is:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

#include "tester.h"

void fee(int i) {}
void foo() {}

ThreadMaster tm;

void add(void(*func)()) {
    tm.add(func);
}

void edd(void(*func)(int), int x) {
    tm.add(func, x);
}

int main() {
    add(foo);
    edd(fee, 6);

    tm.threads[0].join();
    tm.threads[1].join();
}
```

This works, and would be a practical solution as the number of arguments is somewhat limited. However, it is not a real solution for the problem, so I will leave this question open.

Comment: Use variadic templates?

Comment: Please don't use va_list, that's a non type-safe crutch inherited from C. Do as Matthieu said and use (variadic) templates.

Comment: But how do you then handle the varying number of arguments?

Comment: "...that safely handles all threads in the application."  Hmmm.  IMHO threads are for doing things 'asynchronously'.  So, well, what do _you_ mean by 'handling a thread'?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a wrapper for a `std::thread` constructor, so that you can keep all of the `thread` objects in a certain container. So it would make sense to have your wrapper take the same arguments as the constructor.

Taking a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), constructor #3 appears to have the signature you want:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

Adjusting your your member function to this signature:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
void add( Function&& f, Args&&... args ) {
    threads.emplace_back(f, args...);
}
```

(I also changed the `push_back` to `emplace_back` since that seems to be more fitting in this case.) I haven't checked this further than making sure it compiles, but the principle is sound: when making a wrapper, start by copying the function signature.